# .env file vs constants stored in a file. What is the difference?

Tags: javascript, environment-variables, constants

I have been using .env files for some time. I want to know if there are any advantages of using .env file (dotenv-javascript) over storing and using constants a normal .js file?

Thanks :)

Comment: The point of using env files, is to not store environment variables in the code. These variables could contain secrets we don't want users of the code to know.

Comment: But we can store that in a normal '.js' (for ex., constants.js) file as well, right? And import constants from that file whenever required. Does .env handle that process differently?

Comment: `.env` doesn't handle anything. It's just a file. For the use in node we have to import the file and read it, [usually using a library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv). `import` usually requires the file to be in the source control. This is bad if we don't want others to know the info stored there.

Comment: So, that means there is no difference between a `.env` file and any `constants.js` file which just contains constants written like `constant CONST = value` and then export those constants?

Comment: `.env` is a convention. Multiple different tools understand them out-of-the-box, e.g. `docker| and `docker-compose` read the `.env` file by default. AFAIK Java Spring also supports it by default. The advantage is one configuration file that is automatically used by your programs.